# Get Attribute of Label from Django Radioselect Form using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms

I've created a `CustomChoiceField` from a queryset in Django with a custom label that passes the name, url, and aspect attributes of each object into the label. Here's the relevant code from `forms.py`:

```
class CustomChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return mark_safe("<span class='%s'>%s</span><img src='%s' class='teams__filter__image'/>" % (obj.aspect, obj.name, obj.image.url))

filter_pic = CustomChoiceField(required=False, label=mark_safe('Image Filter'), widget=forms.RadioSelect(attrs={'id':'filter-choice'}), queryset=FilterPic.objects.filter(activated=True), empty_label='None')
```

It renders in HTML like so:

```
<p class="teams__form__label">Image Filter</p>
<p><label for="filter-choice_0"><input checked="checked" id="filter-choice_0" name="filter_pic" type="radio" value="" /> None</label></p>
<p><label for="filter-choice_1"><input id="filter-choice_1" name="filter_pic" type="radio" value="2" /> <span class='0.7'>WeHealth Orange</span><img src='/media/images/2017/08/28/orangefilter.png' class='teams__filter__image'/></label></p>
<p><label for="filter-choice_2"><input id="filter-choice_2" name="filter_pic" type="radio" value="1" /> <span class='0.7'>WeHealth Blue</span><img src='/media/images/2017/08/28/bluefilter.png' class='teams__filter__image'/></label></p>
```

Everything looks great in HTML. The problem, is that I need the **aspect** attribute (current the value attribute in the label) in order to trigger a subsequent Javascript function (cropper.js aspect ratio). How can I obtain the aspect value in Javascript?

**EDIT:**

Just to be clear, I was looking for a way to get the class of the label from the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a trigger when the user selects a radio choice:

```
$('input:radio[name="filter_pic"]').change(function() {
```

I then identified the `id` of that choice and found the `class` of the next element (since the aspect ratio was being passed into the class of that element):

```
var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
var aspectClass = $("input[id='"+idVal+"']").next().attr("class");
```

Finally, I set `cropAspect` to equal either that class or a default of 2.0:

```
if (aspectClass) {
    cropAspect = aspectClass;
} else {
    cropAspect = 2;
}
```

Full code below:

```
$('input:radio[name="filter_pic"]').change(function() {
    var idVal = $(this).attr("id");
    var aspectClass = $("input[id='"+idVal+"']").next().attr("class");
    if (aspectClass) {
        cropAspect = aspectClass;
    } else {
        cropAspect = 2;
    }
});
```

I could then pass `cropAspect` into `cropper.js` like so:

```
$image.cropper({
    viewMode: 1,
    aspectRatio: cropAspect,
    minCropBoxWidth: 200,
    minCropBoxHeight: 200,
    rotatable: true,
    scalable: true,
    checkOrientation: true,
    ready: function () {
        $image.cropper("setCanvasData", canvasData);
        $image.cropper("setCropBoxData", cropBoxData);
    }
});
```